# What happens if I install Linux mint on preinstalled partition which has Ubuntu14.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, partitioning

I already have installed Ubuntu14.04 on partition on  my hdd but it is not starting up so I want to install  Linux Mint?Can I do that and what will if I do that?

Comment: Well, if you do that than you have mint installed and ubuntu will be gone.

Comment: But maybe a hint: try solving the issue why ubuntu does not start up.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: What is your actual question?  Obviously, you can replace Ubuntu with Mint.  Would you do this just to solve a boot problem or because you would rather have Mint?  As the question is written, the result would be that Mint would be installed instead of Ubuntu.  Depending on what the boot problem is, the installation might also fix that.  It is also likely that you can fix the boot problem without installing Mint.

Comment: Mint is a relatively minor variant of Ubuntu, so unless you solve the problem within Ubuntu, you'll probably have the same problem with Mint. There are numerous resources for solving Ubuntu boot problems (try http://askubuntu.com or http://ubuntuforums.org, for starters), so please try there, posting more details about how you installed (EFI mode vs. BIOS mode, disk partitioning information, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

> What happens if I install Linux mint on preinstalled partition which has Ubuntu14.04?

As already answered in comments, your Ubuntu 14.04 will be inaccessible(lost) as Linux Mint will format the partition and install its own files.

> Can I do that and what will if I do that?

Yes, you can do that. You can make a live USB or CD/DVD to boot into Linux Mint's live session. About `What will`, you can see how well Mint is working for you in live session. You can install it and can boot into the installed Mint system. That said, it would be premature to say that the current issue with your Ubuntu 14.04 would be reproduced in Mint (Ubuntu variant) as soon as after install, since nothing substantial (other than its not starting up somehow) or even a hint regarding the inaccessibility of Ubuntu is mentioned in question.